# how to share param between service_worker and options_page in chrome extension mv3？

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

We need to share the extension setting between service_worker and options_page in chrome extension mv3,

we could do it by chrome.storage.sync，
but we are wondering is there a better way to achieve it?

```
"background":
  {
    "service_worker": "sw.js"
  },
  "options_page": "option.html",
```

and the option.html got its own option.js

I need to share the param between sw.js and option.js

thank you :)

Comment: Clarify why you don't want chrome.storage.

Comment: because we wondering there's some method like chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage, could directly using ? so we could define one place and use everywhere

Comment: No, but you can use messaging.